# Why isn't Request.Url.Scheme returning HTTPS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, https

I am working on a local server and I need a specific URL to be accessed through HTTPS while the rest through HTTP. I have configured Visual Studio to use IIS Express so I can use HTTP/SSL.

I have a method like so:

```
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult SomeHttpsMethod()
{
     //Do something
}
```

In another place I have:

```
var url = Url.Action("SomeHttpsMethod", "SomeHttpsController", new { someParams }, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

If I access my site using `HTTP` i.e. `http://localhost:httpport`, I still get `HTTP` returned from `Request.Url.Scheme` instead of `HTTPS`. Is that how it is meant to work?

Obviously if I accesss my site using `HTTPS` i.e. to begin with i.e. `https://localhost:sslport`, `HTTPS` is returned (which is what I want) but I don't want to have to access the site in `HTTPS`, only for that particular URL/controller method.

Comment: This is because `Request.Url.Scheme` get's the scheme of the *current request*, which *is* http.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line:

```
var url = Url.Action("SomeHttpsMethod", "SomeHttpsController", 
    new { someParams }, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

constructs a URL based on your *current* request's scheme, which is HTTP. `Request` always refers to the current request.

You'd be better off hard-coding "https" in this place since you always want it to be secure anyway:

```
var url = Url.Action("SomeHttpsMethod", "SomeHttpsController", 
    new { someParams }, "https");
```

Comment: Ok, so that does return the correct protocol. What happens to the port? It returns me a url ```https://localhost/somehttpsmethod``` which I am unable to connect to, since it needs to  be ```https://localhost:44300/somehttpsmethod```.

Comment: This is where IIS Express falls apart. You'd be best to switch to IIS which is much more robust and uses standard ports (80 and 443).

Comment: I see. So the above code will work properly on an IIS with a valid SSL certificate?

Comment: Or even an invalid self-signed certificate for local testing. It's no big deal that it's invalid for your local PC only - the public isn't using it. You just have to click through the browser warnings on being unable to verify it.

Comment: @Haney you can use port 80 and 443 so long as you run IIS-Express / VS as administrator, alternatively, you can muck about with command line stuff to enable SSL on port 443 for use with IIS-Express.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was down to badly set up rules on the ARR server. Just something to look at if you get HTTP rather than HTTPS.

Comment: What's ARR? Advanced acronyms are very unhelpful in answers on a site meant to explain problems and solutions.

Comment: ARR = Application Request Routing. It is an IIS extension that allows an application server to function as a load balancer.